# How can more than one person use Tortoise SVN?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

We have a team of developers working on same software project. We would like to create a central Subversion repository, and where everybody can submit their code using TortoiseSVN, sitting from different computers on a network (LAN).

How we can track that who has done which change on code?

Comment: You really need to read the [Subversion manual](http://svnbook.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Right-Click the file you want to check and click `Annotate` or `Blame`, depending on your version of Tortoise SVN.

[Official Tortoise Blame manual](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-blame.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can add users. So when they are committing the code, svn will log the user who made the commit along with time and other details.